# Как включить подсветку typedef'ов в Clion'е

Tags: c++, clion

При объявлении своего типа, он не подсвечивается))
Хотелось что-бы хоть как-то подсвечивалось, а не просто белый текст.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такие штуки обычно называются "semantic highlighting", попробуйте это погуглить.

Comment: Он подсвечивается серым.